# Wordpress Gutenberg Ajax request

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm new to react and gutenberg so kind of lost a bit.  I am trying to get an array of posts from a custom post type.  Then loop through those posts and register a block for each one. I can everything else, just having trouble with getting the posts.

Here's my js file.

```
( function( blocks, element, editor, components, data ) {
    var el = element.createElement;
    var InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
    var PanelBody = wp.components.PanelBody;

    var CustomPostsTypePosts = //this is where I want to get the posts;

    CustomPostTypePosts.forEach(function(element) {
        //now I will register a block for each post here
        blocks.registerBlockType();
    });


}(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.data,
    window.wp.editor,
    window.wp.components

) );
```

Comment: Try e.g. `var CustomPostsTypePosts  = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords( 'postType','my-cpt-slug',{ per_page: 10 } );` with your custom post type slug as `'my-cpt-slug'` or use the `data` input argument. Watch out for typos in variable names.

Comment: I tried this `var Properties = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords( 'postType','ccproperty',{ per_page: -1 } );
    console.log( Properties );` But its returning `length:0` eventhough I have posts

Comment: Does it work for posts or pages? Does it work if you paste it to the browser's console?